# Find the smallest $α$ for which $S + αI$ is regular

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

The question goes: find the smallest $α$ for which $S + αI$ is regular.

My attempt on the solution:
If a matrix is regular, than the determinant of the matrix is not $0$.
But I am not sure, how to implement it, or there was a better, nicer solution to this question using eigenvectors or eigenvalues.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed an eigenvalue issue. Matrix $S+\alpha I$ is regular iff

$$\det(S+\alpha I) \ne 0 \tag{1}$$

Comparing to the classical equation $\det(S-\lambda I)=0$ condition (1) means that $-\alpha$ is not an eigenvalue of $S$.

Two cases:

- either all eigenvalues of $S$ are complex ; in this case, there is no smaller $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
- or $S$ has at least a real eigenvalue. Therefore, in this case $\alpha$ must be larger than the largest of the $(-\lambda_k)$ (considering only real values). Strictly speaking, there is no **minimal** value for $\alpha$.